# Creating a method that will convert an Int into a String into the main using Java

Tags: java, methods

I can't figure out where to even start with this problem, I have to take a score that can be earned in a football game and have a method convert that score into a string up in the main.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int correctCount = 0;
    if (translateScore(2).equals("safety") == true) { correctCount++;}
    if (translateScore(3).equals("field goal") == true) { correctCount++;}
    if (translateScore(6).equals("touchdown") == true) { correctCount++;}
    if (translateScore(7).equals("touchdown and extra point") == true) { correctCount++;}
    if (translateScore(8).equals("touchdown and 2-point conversion") == true) { correctCount++;}
    if (translateScore(-1).equals("") == true) { correctCount++;}
    if (translateScore(1).equals("invalid") == true) { correctCount++;}
    if (translateScore(10).equals("you must be playing Quidditch ") == true) { correctCount++;}
    if (correctCount == 8) {
        System.out.println("All tests passed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("At least one test failed");
    }
}

public static String translateScore (int score) {
    return "";  
}
```

Comment: How are you going to "get" the score? will it be passed as a starting parameter in the console?

Comment: And don't compare boolean values to `true`; it's already either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Integer.toString does exist... as well as int + "";

Comment: Why are you translating scores? It seems like it would be a lot more efficient to forgo the translation process in the first place. If you NEED to translate scores, I'd recommend a set of if statements that assign the correct score? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do. Could you make that a little clearer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but if you're looking to "convert" a few different `int`s into some fixed strings, then perhaps you could use a switch/case:

```
public static String translateScore(int score) {
    switch (score) {
    case 2:
        return "safety";
    case 3:
        return "field goal";
    // other cases...
    default:
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: essentially the method must take a score of say 7, and then send that score up to the main where it prints out as "touchdown". I can't change anything in the main, so everything has to happen in the translateScore method,

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding you, or you're misunderstanding the assignment. `translateScore` returns a `String`, so it can't "send that score up to the main". It can however return one of the fixed Strings you have in `main`.